# Is the phrase "please kindly" redundant?

Tags: email, redundancy

The colleagues in my office often send email starting with "Please kindly". Are the two phrases a bit redundant?

Comment: I just want to point out that I disagree with the implicit assumption here that there is something inherently wrong with redundancy.

Comment: While the opening *Please kindly* isn't wrong, per se, it's frequently overused by non-native speakers and Indian English speakers, in my experience. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: Half the emails in my email _spam_ folder start with "please kindly".

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14478/indian-english-usage-of-kindly

Answer (score 16):

Strictly speaking, "please" and "kindly" do serve separate purposes. I can demand that you kindly do a certain task:

> *Kindly* apologize to your mother

The intent is to dictate how you should apologize. Prepending "please" is *me* politely asking you to do something:

> Please apologize to your mother

Combining them signifies that I am being polite and you should be polite:

> Please kindly apologize to your mother

In the context of office chatter, I would interpret the original intent of the phrase to mean, "I am asking nicely; don't give me attitude." As it is now bordering on a cliché, I highly doubt anyone is putting much thought into the phrase or its meaning and they are simply being polite.

Comment: No, the sentence "Kindly apologize to your mother" is not generally used to instruct the listener *how* to apologize (by analogy with possible locutions such as "Quickly apologize to your mother") but to soften the imperative speech act.  It is equivalent in this context to "please".

Answer (score 9):

Both the adverbs are used in polite requests, and one of the meanings of *kindly* is *please*.

In a sentence like "please kindly send me a copy of your paperwork," *please* and *kindly* are redundant.

In a sentence like "will you kindly sign the enclosed copy of this letter," *kindly* is often used ironically.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are redundant, as in this context, they mean essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, *kindly* is an intensifier. It's similar in use to *very* in the phrase *I am very disappointed in you*.

Sure it's redundant, sure it's unnecessary, but it signifies a slightly higher tone of politeness.

Answer (score 0):

What would you prefer me to ask you? *Please, would you kindly pass me the magazine*, or *pass me the magazine*.

The *please, kindly* adds a layer of "politeness" (for want of a better word), and, although effectively it is redundant, it changes the sentence from a request to an order.

Comment: Out of those options the first one, obviously, but is there really any difference between *Please kindly pass me the magazine* and *Please pass me the magazine* (which I think is the point of this question)

Comment: @Jonik There is a slight difference in tone, just as there is a slight difference between *I am disappointed in you* and *I am very disappointed in you*.