# please *kindly* disregard

Tags: expressions, redundancy

Not sure if my question is considered redundant to another one that was asked of `if "please kindly" generally is a redundant expression`.

I am curious if 
`"please disregard my message"` is polite enough or
if `"please kindly disregard my message"` is necessary.

Or if `"please kindly disregard my message"` is actually a redundant expression, as there is no `kindly` or `unkindly` way of disregarding a message.

Comment: Who are you writing for? Using one or the other is "polite enough" for the vast majority of Brits, Yanks, and Aussies (among others); overly demonstrative or obsequious politeness will be irritating rather than ingratiating. People in other cultures, however, may be accustomed to more elaborate demonstrations of deference; see e.g. *[Indian-English usage of “Kindly”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14478)* and *[What's the deal with “thank you kindly”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55771)*

Comment: not sure how to mark my own question as a duplicate. Thanks a lot for the input and 'please kindly' help mark it.

Answer (score -1):

> I am curious if "please disregard my message" is polite enough or if "please kindly disregard my message" is necessary?

I like 'please kindly', use it myself and it passes  superficial grammar checks even if it is somewhat redundant.

https://app.grammarly.com/docs/258541700

Comment: @ibf, are you indian